# How do i extract title of given url as string and store it in a text file in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup

This is the code in python i have written:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/iit-bombay-birds-eye-view-and-quantum-biology/article18191268.ece"
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext,"lxml")
webpage_title = soup.find_all('h1', attrs = {"class": "title"})
print webpage_title
```

This is output that i am getting:

```
 [<h1 class="title">\nIIT Bombay: Bird\u2019s eye view and quantum biology\n</h1>]
```

I want the output to be:

```
IIT Bombay: Bird’s eye view and quantum biology
```

And i want this output to be stored as string so that i can write it to a file.

I do not want the title to be in unicode.

If so then i want a way to convert unicode to ascii string.

Answer (score 0):

```
webpage_title = webpage_title[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

By default BS reads the request content as `utf-8`.

Comment: Replace your `webpage_title = ...` by that one

Comment: But now how do i write this webpage_title as text into a file?             
              UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)        .pls help with this.